# Override file in META-INF

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In my project, I have a dependency whose Jar-file contains the file `META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties`. For a particular reason, I want to replace this file entirely with my own version. I googled and found out that I can add files to `META-INF` by simply creating the file as such:

```
src/resources/META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties
```

This works, as long as the file I wish to add and the file that already exists have different names. But if they have the same name, the maven-assembly-plugin uses the file from the dependency instead of using my file. How can I fix that?

Configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
        <mainClass>com.github.vatbub.autoHotkeyNounReplacer.CreateAutoHotkeyScriptKt</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
        <Implementation-Build>20210702123553</Implementation-Build>
        <Custom-Implementation-Build>20210702123553</Custom-Implementation-Build>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you can ensure your file is first on the classpath, that's the one that should get used, but that's not necessarily easy with Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself: The maven shade plugin allows much finer control over how the assembled jar is created. I hence replaced the maven-assembly-plugin with the maven-shade-plugin with the following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>org.languagetool:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>${mainClass}</Main-Class>
                    <!-- custom manifest entries -->
                </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```